# Emit Observable value and handle it in component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-observable

I have a `login()` method an `AuthService`. What I want is to emit value from `login()` method in `AuthService` to handle value in `NavbarComponent`:

```
export class AuthService extends AbstractRestService<any> {
    user: AppUser = {id: null}; 

    login(userName: string, password: string) {
        return this.http
            .post('/auth/login')
                .pipe(
                    map(res => {
                    // here I want to emit value of Observable `anUser$` 
                    // to send value to NavbarComponent
                        this.getAppUser(); // I want to throw Observable value to handle its value 
                                           // in NavbarComponent.ts         

                        return true;
                  })
                 , catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }

    public getAppUser(): Observable<AppUser> {   
        return of(this.user);

    }
}
```

My `NavbarComponent.html` looks like this:

```
<li *ngIf="appUser$ | async as anUser">

 {{ anUser?.name }}

</li>
```

My `NavbarComponent.ts` looks like this:

```
appUser$: Observable<AppUser>;

async ngOnInit() {
    this.appUser$ = this.auth.getAppUser();    
}
```

What I want is to emit value from `login()` method in `AuthService` to handle value in `NavbarComponent`, however value of `appUser$` is not shown in `NavbarComponent.html`.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this:

```
export class AuthService extends AbstractRestService<any> {
    user: AppUser = {id: null}; 

    login(userName: string, password: string) {
        return this.http
            .post('/auth/login')
                .pipe(
                    map(res => {
                        this.userSource.next(res); // just call next with the user here       

                        return true;
                  })
                 , catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }

    private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<AppUser>({id: null})
    public getAppUser = this.userSource.asObservbale();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you show the way where ‘ getAppUser()’ will not be changed because this method has more logic than I’ve shown.

Comment: you need to change getAppUser, the way you've implemented it is the problem in your code.  All you could do is keep it as a function by doing like `getAppUser() { /* whatever */ return this.userSource.asObservable(); }`

Comment: thank you very much! It works! You've said *it is the problem in your code*. I will be very glad to hear how this method can be improved. Could you tell me how this method can be improved?

Answer (score 3):

By returning `of(this.user)` from the method `getUser()` all you're doing is returning the an observable with a single emission that is the value of `this.user` at the time of the call.

If you want a stream that will be updated every time the user is updated by login then the best way to do that would be to use a **Subject**.  A Subject is an Observable that whose emissions can be set from the outside.

You probably want to use a special subject called **BehaviorSubject** that will emit the last value as soon as it is subscribed too.  This way if login was already called after the observable is subscribed to then the current value will still be returned. It is equivalent to a regular observable with *startWith* and *shareReplay* operator.

```
export class AuthService extends AbstractRestService<any> {
  private readonly userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{ id: string }>();



  login(userName: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post('/auth/login')
      .pipe(
         tap(res => userSubject.next(res)),
         catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getAppUser() {
    /** do other work **/
    return this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Personally, I would just assign the variable directly by exposing `userSubject` as a readonly field using `this.userSubject.asObservable()`.  Since you indicated you have additional logic occurring in `getAppUser()`, you can just do the same call in the method.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you show the way where ‘ getAppUser()’ will not be changed because this method has more logic than I’ve shown.